# Google Sheets ImportXML returning Content is Empty

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, xml-parsing, google-sheets-formula

I'm working to extract into Google Sheets data from the following link:

https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/nba-basketball/pointspread/1st-quarter/

Specifically, I'm trying to extract the Q1 Spreads from below the "bovada" column. I am trying to use ImportXML within Google Sheets, however, the Xpath query doesn't seem to be working (or I'm using it incorrectly).

I thought following formula would get me the initial piece of data (B1 stores my URL):

`=importxml(B1,"//[@id="bettingOddsGridContainer"]/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/section[5]/main/div[1]/span/span[1]")`

However, from working backwards, it seems that at div[2] it cuts out. I.e., when I run the following formula, I'm still receiving results but once I add div[2] it cuts out and says that it's not importing any data.

```
=importxml(B2,"//*[@id='bettingOddsGridContainer']/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div/div")
```

Any thoughts or help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not see any xml on the link.  Did your query specify that you wanted xml?

Comment: It's calling for an xpath_query, which per basic research should fit the string i'm entering. That said, i'm not super familiar with xml querying, so I'm wondering if possibly my XML query is off.

Comment: The link you provided is html not xml.  So the method importxml will not work.  You either need to change the query to one that returns xml or use another method.

Comment: Gotcha - perhaps that's the point of my confusion. But, is there a reason then that you could think of why the second formula i posted works in google sheets, but the first doesn't? Or if what I posted is HTML code (not an xpath) are you aware of an well-functioning HTML --> Xpath converters? Thanks!

Comment: Some html will parse in xml and others won't. html and xml are similar  You shouldn't be using an xml parse for html.

Comment: Makes sense - i'll look further into html parses for google sheets and/or finding the appropriate xml code. thanks for the help!